# if else block in Dart gives error on semicolon

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm passing a function to a widget like this:

```
  onSwap: () => {
            if (OrientationSingleton.left) {
              OrientationSingleton.left = false;
              SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight])
            } else {
              OrientationSingleton.left = true;
              SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft])
            }
          }
```

On the widget, it is

```
final Function onSwap;
```

However, I get an error in the semicolon of `OrientationSingleton.left = false;`:

```
Expected to find '}'.
```

This makes no sense to me. There's no error on my `{`.

Cleaning everything to

```
onSwap: () => {
            }
```

works so there's no missing `{`

Comment: Except you are now returning an empty Hash for that last example. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove `=>` and add `;` 
code snippet

```
onSwap: () {
            if (OrientationSingleton.left) {
              OrientationSingleton.left = false;
              SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);
            } else {
              OrientationSingleton.left = true;
              SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove arrow(=>) and add ";" end of statements.